# How to get time stamps from a tiff stack using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, timestamp, tiff, exif, imagej

I have a time series of about 100,000 tiff images and I want to get the time stamps in an excel sheet or a txt file. I used the following code in python to get the image metadata

```
import exifread
f = open(photopath)
tags = exifread.process_file(f)
```

When I do this, I get a lot of metadata, but not the time stamps. This is the output I get

```
{'Image BitsPerSample': (0x0102) Short=16 @ 417654,
'Image Compression': (0x0103) Short=Uncompressed @ 417666,
'Image ImageDescription': (0x010E) ASCII=Created by Hamamats, ... ] @ 417830,
'Image ImageLength': (0x0101) Short=348 @ 417642,
'Image ImageWidth': (0x0100) Short=600 @ 417630,
'Image Orientation': (0x0112) Short=Horizontal (normal) @ 417714,
'Image PageNumber': (0x0129) Short=[0, 0] @ 417786,
'Image PhotometricInterpretation': (0x0106) Short=1 @ 417678,
'Image PlanarConfiguration': (0x011C) Short=1 @ 417762,
'Image ResolutionUnit': (0x0128) Short=Pixels/Inch @ 417774,
'Image RowsPerStrip': (0x0116) Short=348 @ 417738,
'Image SampleFormat': (0x0153) Short=Unsigned @ 417798,
'Image SamplesPerPixel': (0x0115) Short=1 @ 417726,
'Image StripByteCounts': (0x0117) Long=417600 @ 417750,
'Image StripOffsets': (0x0111) Long=8 @ 417702,
'Image SubfileType': (0x00FE) Long=Single page of multi-page image @ 417618,
'Image Tag 0xFFFB': (0xFFFB) Byte=16 @ 417810,
'Image Tag 0xFFFC': (0xFFFC) Long=[1, 4294967295L] @ 418368}
```

When I open the file in ImageJ, I can see the timestamps. But I can only see them one image at a time. Is there any way to see the time stamps in python? Is it possible that exifread is looking for the wrong keyword in the tiff file header for the time stamp?

Thanks
Sara

Comment: did you try setting the debug parameter to process_file?

Comment: do you find the timestamps in ImageJ image properties? What's the name of the tag? Or is it the timestamp of the file in the OS?

Comment: If those are the only tags in the TIFF files, then there is no timestamp. Do you know what the last 2 private tags contain? Also, why aren't you using a lossless compression like LZW or Flate on those images? Could probably shrink them between 2 and 5x.

Comment: In Image J, I look under Image >> Show Info . And the label there is Time_from_start and Time_from_last

Comment: And here is a link to the google drive folder that has a zip file containing a few of the tiff files in case someone wants to try to get the time stamps. https://drive.google.com/a/usc.edu/file/d/0B-UUDROd7kxJdzZ6TmlPT0hVbzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I examined your TIFF files. THERE ARE NO TIMESTAMP TAGS. File systems maintain a creation data and modification date, but within your files there is no explicit timestamp - period.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get in touch with the people at Hamamatsu and got  response from them that solved the problem. Apparently their camera acquistion software stores the time stamps inside the "Image Description" Tag inside the imfinfo structure. I guess that was their way of making things easier for themselves and more confusing for the users. They output pretty much all the info about the tiff file inside the "Image Description" Tag. 
Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Regards
Sara